# How to set data-id to webgrid column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I am using webgrid to show some data.I want to assign class, data-id, data-propertyname attributes to 'td' element when the code converts to html in browser.

```
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
        selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        firstText: "first",
        previousText: "previous",
        nextText: "next",
        lastText: "last",
        emptyRowCellValue: "",
        numericLinksCount: 10,
        columns:grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(null,null,format:@<text><input value="@item.Id" type="checkbox" id="id" name="id" /></text>),
            grid.Column("Id", header: "S.No. ↕", format:@<text>@item.Id</text>),
            grid.Column("Tower", header: "Tower ↕", format:@<text><div class="editSelect" data-id="@item.Id" data-propertyname="Tower">@item.Tower</div></text>),
    //rest of the columns


    //Currently the code converts like this in the browser:
    <td><div class="editSelect" data-id="@item.Id" data-propertyname="Tower">Tower 1</div></td>
    //But I want it to be like :
    <td class="editSelect" data-id="@item.Id" data-propertyname="Tower">Tower 1</td>
```